# How do I programmatically stop execution of a python script, without closing python and maintaining the variables?

Tags: python, variables, memory, exit

I have an object oriented program and I want to stop execution and maintain the python memory of all the variables that were in memory during execution.

I want to do that so that I can experiment with my variables and program with them in the python shell.

sys.exit() finish python execution, not only the script, it is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the following Python statements should solve your problem. It involves using the debugger.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: This is the tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is to debug your program, try pdb which is the python debugger

http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Or if you prefer you can use Eclipse with PyDevelop to have a friendlier user interface :)